# How to disable TypeScript Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true })?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

The ts compiler emit this line in every file:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

But my code is running on Nodejs, I am not writing a libaray so I think this line is unnecessary for me. How can I disable it?
My compiler option is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    }
}
```

For example, compile this ts file:

```
function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
}

export { add }
```

I got:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
exports.add = add;
//# sourceMappingURL=App.js.map
```

How can I remove the second line?

Comment: It's not unnecessary. It's used to check how to import packages (ie with importing the default export).

Comment: @AndrewLi So the check is done by Node.js?

Comment: Well, no. It's for ES6 modules. When you import a module in ES2015, and that code is transpiled to ES5, the importee has to check if the module is an ES6 module and import accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewLi Got it:) thanks

Answer (score -17, accepted):

> But my code is running on Nodejs, I am not writing a libaray so I think this line is unnecessary for me. How can I disable it

It works fine. So don't remove it. Think of it like `"use strict"`. It's not *neccessary* but its good to have.

It exists to allow interop between transpilers (typescript / babel / other future ones).

Comment: That's not an answer, that's an opinion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54619111/4794368