# Typescript & Electron exports is not defined

Tags: typescript, electron, commonjs

I'm trying to run my simple electron app. I use Typescript as a development language which compiles into JavaScript. When I run the app I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined[Learn More]
file:///Users/ahmet/Documents/JumbleUp-Desktop/dist/Login/Login.js:5
exports.__esModule = true;
```

My login.ts file looks like this

```
    import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        location.replace("index.html");
    } else {
        location.replace("login.html");
    }
  });
function login() {
    const userEmail = (document.getElementById("inputEmail") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const userPassword = (document.getElementById("inputPassword") as HTMLInputElement).value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...

        window.alert("Alert : " + errorMessage);
      });
}
```

and here my tsconfig file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*"]
      }
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: please show us the compiled login.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: none of the solutions of the above mentioned link fixed my problem.

Answer (score 23):

I've encountered the same problem. For me the problem was not in the way the files are transpiled, but by how they were included in the project in `index.html`.

Changing:

```html
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

to

```html
<script>
   require("./main.js")
</script>
```

in index.html

solved it for me

Comment: HI @kuba-orlik, unfortunately, after making the change at the `index.html`, now I am getting `require is not defined` instead - have you seen this when you made the change? 

(I know this answer was submitted about 3 years ago so thank you anyway :-) )

Comment: No, in my case it just started working. Maybe it's got something to do with the contents of the js file that you `require`? Have you tried a minimal case where the index.html has only one `require` and it points to a basic js file with like `alert("it works")` in it?

Comment: Thanks for getting back! It also started working for me as well (probably after I had set `nodeIntegration` under `webPreferences` to `true` when creating the `BrowserWindow`)

Comment: It worked but I had to add 'unsafe-inline' to the Content-Security-Policy.

Original:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">`

Working:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">`