# Looking for a _working_ simple example of Electron v8 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, electron

Forgive the simplicity of my plaintiff question, I'm close to my wits end.

I am looking for a *working* simple example of Electron v8 and TypeScript. It needn't include WebPack, Babel, React or anything else. Nothing I have found seems to work with Electron v8.

## Update

My prior statement remind me of Macbeth's line *it is a tale
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, Signifying nothing*, so let's state the problem in **detail** this time.

The [stock Electron & Typescript example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript) does not demonstrate the following:

- Using `import` for Node modules within the renderer process
- Using `import` for my own application modules within the renderer process.

Attempting to do so got no errors from `tsc` but provoked a runtime error

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined[Learn More]
exports.__esModule = true
```

Using `require` instead of `import`, especially for classes like `EventEmitter` upset VS Code which warned

```
'EventEmitter' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)
```

... so that's a backward step.

Setting `target` in `tsconfig.json` to `ES2018` means I *can* use ES6 modules and the `import` syntax for my own modules, though it needs a `.js` suffix to work.

```
import {blah} from './MyModule.js'` // Shouldn't need that suffix!
```

VS Code gives the impression that I can `import` Node modules, but it still fails at runtime.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "events". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which I shall detail here, and you can find [available in code here](https://github.com/martin-cowie/electron-quick-start-typescript).

You can use `import` in the renderer process for both Node modules and your own modules making these changes:

1. When constructing your `BrowserWindow` in the main process, set `nodeIntegration` to `true`.
2. When loading your JavaScript code from within your HTML page use `<script>require('./renderer.js')</script>` instead of the more conventional `<script src="./renderer.js"></script>`.

Credit for most of this goes to @kuba-orlik in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619111/typescript-electron-exports-is-not-defined), which sent me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You'll require four things: `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `index.ts` and `index.html`.

I've based my example on a [Electron tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app) and a blog post on working with [Electron and TypeScript](https://medium.com/@davembush/typescript-and-electron-the-right-way-141c2e15e4e1).

The `package.json` needs to bring in Electron and TypeScript dependencies, trigger the TypeScript build and start Electron.

```
{
  "name": "electron-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "tsc",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "8.0.1",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

The prestart script compiles the TypeScript and start runs Electron using the project as the application directory. I don't know the minimum version of TypeScript needed but it's 3 something.

The `tsconfig.json` needs to set some compiler options and identify what to build when running `tsc`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true 
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"] 
}
```

This will compile any TypeScript files it finds outside of `node_modules` and generate the JavaScript alongside them.

The `index.ts` needs to create a browser window and load the landing page.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

function createWindow () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

This is some boilerplate code for starting Electron, all the types are infered.

Finaly the `index.html` needs to display something you can recognise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

This will display the versions of node, Chrome and Electron.

With these files in the same directory, running `npm start` should compile the TypeScript and start the Electron application.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any simple electron typescript starter example either... so I created my own.

[Here's my repository](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/electron-typescript-quick-start). It's based on the [official quick start starter](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) (but with typescript).

I also added electron-builder for easily building disturbable packages.

```sh
# install dependencies
$ npm install

# compile typescript files
$ npm run compile

# watch typescript files for changes
$ npm run watch

# run the app
$ npm start

# create distributable packages for specific platforms
$ npm run dist-linux
$ npm run dist-mac
$ npm run dist-windows
```

Comment: Thanks @matt-champion for the `prestart` script tip